# Expo Sound in Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, arrow-functions

I'm trying to create a Whatsapp alike with react-native (All components in arrow functions) and Expo but the AudioPlayer component doesn't work because the rerender of useState declares the Audio.Sound() more than once.

I did not find examples of converting Class Based to Function when you have to declare new objects.

```
const AudioPlayer = props => {

    const sound = new Audio.Sound();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
            await sound.loadAsync(require('../../assets/sounds/notification.mp3'));
        })();
    });
}
```

I declared Sound object outside AudioPlayer but when I try to use the component twice, only the first works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useEffect hook in React takes another argument, that is an array of dependencies. If any of the dependency change, the useEffect hook will run again. If you wish to run useEffect only on the initial mount and unmount, like we do in Class based component in ComponentDidMount and ComponentWillUnmount, you can pass an empty array. Also as the other answer suggested, you can use a ref to keep track of the sound object for each component.

```
const AudioPlayer = props => {

const sound = useRef(new Audio.Sound());

React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        sound.current.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
        await sound.current.loadAsync(require('../../assets/sounds/notification.mp3'));
    })();
}, []); // added an empty array
```

}

Now the useEffect hook will not run on any state change.

Also you can make your code concise by using the
[createAsync function provided by Expo Audio](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#playing-sounds).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

expo av function component example

```js
  
 import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
 
 
const on_press_handle = ()=>{
 
 
 // it shuld be async function .
 (async () => {
         const play_yes = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
         require('../assets/sounds/no.wav'),
                        { shouldPlay: true }
                        );
                })();
                
                
}
```